# Преобразования JSON в таблицу HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, table

Просьба, подсказать, как корректно перебрать подобную `json` конструкцию для формирования html таблицы

```
const response = {"ab":{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"},
                "ac":{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"},
                "ad":{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"},
                "af":{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"},
                "ar":{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"},
                "ae":{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"},
                "ac":{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"}}
```

на выходе получить

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ab</td>
                <td>ac</td>
                <td>ad</td>
                <td>af</td>
                <td>ar</td>
                <td>ae</td>
                <td>ac</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

пробовал подобным способом, но возвращает только одну строку в таблицу:

```
const tr = document.createElement('tr');
const value = Object.values(response);

value.forEach((key, item) => {
    
    console.log(key[item]);
    $(tr).append('<td>'+key[item]+'</td>');
    
})
console.log(tr)
$('tbody').append(tr)
```

Comment: Извините, а какой ответ Вы ожидаете кроме как: "Надо написать программу для этого"? Что Вы пробовали сделать? Какие проблемы у Вас возникли?

Comment: @AlexYu я пробовал перебрать следующем путем
const tr = document.createElement('tr')

for (const [title, content] of Object.entries(response)){
    const thead = '<td>'+title+'</td>';
    $(tr).append(thead)
    $('#thead').append(tr);

    for (key in content){
        const td = '<td>'+content[key]+'</td>';
    }


};
в момент перебора content и вставке в таблицу данные встали не корректно, как <tr>
                <td>1</td>

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите ваши попытки в вопросе. Под вопросом есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1328660/edit).

Comment: Я вовсе не понимаю зачем вам в json'е такой сложный объект. Также я не вижу, куда делись: 0,3,4,5,6,7,8 . Мне кажется ваш json должен включать массивы.
К примеру первая строка ```"ab":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]``` . Возможно вы не знали, что в JSON присутствуют массивы которые более логичны для построения таблиц.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko привел одну из попыток, удалось корректно составить строку, но таблица заполняется только одной строкой

Comment: @xcplat я бы вам советовал про работу с DOM почитать сначала, например здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document  Также желательно про объекты https://learn.javascript.ru/object  Там достаточно понятно описано. Метод ```.createElement``` создает DOM узел, а метод ```.append``` помещает один узел в другой. Вы создали один узел ```tr```, поэтому у вас одна строка в таблице. Попробуйте создать узел ```tr``` в цикле. Имхо для ```td``` лучше тоже создавать узлы для каждого ```td``` и  уже этим узлам свойство ```textContent``` делать. Исходный объект у вас отвратный.

Comment: Если с ```ab```, ```ac``` еще понятно что это ```textContent``` для ```tr```, то вот это ```{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8"}``` вообще непонятно зачем и что это. На этапе формирования этого объекта что-то пошло не так, видимо

Comment: @freestyle_HD, да, вы правы, формирование кривое выходит из за чего проблемы с перебором, переписываю формирование в ручную во избежания подобных ситуаций

Comment: @ xcplat я там писал, что вы можете попробовать создать DOM-узел ```tr``` в цикле, но просто создать узел недостаточно, тк он на странице не появится. Чтобы он появился его надо добавить(заапендить) с пом. метода ```append``` тоже в цикле

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const response = {
  "ab": { "0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8" },
  "ac": { "0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8" },
  "ad": { "0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8" },
  "af": { "0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8" },
  "ar": { "0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8" },
  "ae": { "0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5","5":"6","6":"7","7":"8" },
};

// преобразование столбцов в строки, и извлечение заголовков
const tableData = { headers: Object.keys(response), rows: [] };
for (const header of tableData.headers) {
  Object.values(response[header]).forEach((val, idx) => {
    (tableData.rows[idx] = (tableData.rows[idx] ?? [])).push(val);
  });
}
// рендеринг таблицы
const tBody = document.createElement('table').createTBody();
tBody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', `<thead><tr>${
  tableData.headers.map(hdr => `<th>${hdr}</th>`).join('')
}</tr></thead>`);
for (const row of tableData.rows) {
  const tr = tBody.insertRow();
  row.forEach(val => tr.insertCell().textContent = val);
}
document.body.appendChild(tBody.parentElement);
```

```css
table  { border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { min-width: 3ch; padding: 0.25em 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

В литерале объекта `response` убрал дублирующееся свойство `ac` - потому что в результате имеет значение только самое последнее объявление свойства (предыдущие объявления с тем же именем свойства "игнорируются").

---

Если не нравится ES11+, то оператор `??` тут можно безболезненно заменить на `||`. В остальном, используются возможности уже старенького ES6 (`for..of`, стрелочные функции, шаблонные строки).